# Handdrawn Lines for Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

How would you extend [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com) to accomplish a "hand-drawn" effect (example: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-and-line-mix/?theme=chalk ).

Or can it be done using a library?

Comment: See the documentation on Themes: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes

Answer (score 0):

Implementing that in Highcharts requires some core code analyzing and wrapping/overwriting `SVGRenderer` methods.

**Example**

Column points are SVG `rect`'s shapes:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/ColumnSeries.js

**`translate`** function:

```
        // Register shape type and arguments to be used in drawPoints
        point.shapeType = 'rect';
```

**`drawPoints`** function:

```
                point.graphic = graphic =
                    renderer[point.shapeType](shapeArgs)
                        .add(point.group || series.group);
```

**`SVGRenderer`** (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/SvgRenderer.js) contains `rect` method that can be wrapperd/overwritten so that it returns the complex path (handwritten effect) instead of simple `rect` tag.

**Docs about wrapping/overwriting:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts